Permission Error while installing Prophet 1.1.5 on SQL Server 2019
I am trying to install a package called prophet (version 1.1.5) on SQL Server 2019. The machine that I'm installing this on has no internet, and so I installed the .whl file associated with prophet (along with the .whl files of all its dependencies). However, when I try the following script:
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python', @script = N' from prophet import Prophet print("hi")' 

I get this error:

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MYSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\prophet'.

I don't know what could be possibly going wrong. This is the more in-depth stack trace for those wondering:
An external script error occurred:C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MYSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\functions\RxSummary.py:4: FutureWarning: The Panel class is removed from pandas. Accessing it from the top-level namespace will also be removed in the next version
from pandas import DataFrame, Index, PanelImporting plotly failed. Interactive plots will not work.
Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "\<string\>", line 5, in \<module\>

 File "C:\\ProgramData\\MYSERVER\\Temp-PY\\Appcontainer1\\EF9BDB92-0B07-4DB3-A04C-1BF2CC77A1A8\\sqlindb_0.py", line 31, in transform

 from prophet import Prophet

 File "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL15.MYSERVER\\PYTHON_SERVICES\\lib\\site-packages\\prophet_init\_.py", line 11, in \<module\>

 here = Path(file).parent.resolve()

 Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 0

 An external script error occurred:

 File "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL15.MYSERVER\\PYTHON_SERVICES\\lib\\pathlib.py", line 1134, in resolve

 s = self.\_flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)

 File "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL15.MYSERVER\\PYTHON_SERVICES\\lib\\pathlib.py", line 192, in resolve

 s = self.\_ext_to_normal(\_getfinalpathname(s))

 PermissionError: \[WinError 5\] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL15.MYSERVER\\PYTHON_SERVICES\\lib\\site-packages\\prophet'

I tried to install the newest version of prophet (1.1.5), but this didn't work. I also tried to run this command (from prophet import Prophet) with the python executable found in MSSQL15.MYSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES and this didn't have any error, which makes me think it is an error on the SQL Server end.
This is also a little bit weird because I've installed other packages (like holidays, cmdstanpy, and zipp) and when I import those packages into SQL Server there are no errors.
